# How to change css properties depending on parent, but with the same class name

Tags: javascript, css

An example: I've got a feed on website, feeds are using same CSS classes, and images have different height. And I need to get height of each of that images and depending on it set a bottom property for a menu, which will be at the bottom of each image on feed.

I plan to use JavaScript.

I stacked on that issue. I'm wondering how to set bottom property for each `menu_div`, depending on images…
So main problem is how to set it to all of them, beacause all images are different.

Feed looks like this:[example](http://macagoraga.com/pinfox/)

And it is not about a particular case, it is about a method.

Comment: can u show some demo ... as like your html css ya image result

Comment: it's not needed actually, i just want to know the method. How it is usually done... maybe using CSS only...
But menu_div has absolute position set...
In example link, you can see how the feed looks like...

Comment: @RohitAzad 

`$('#js_feed_content div.activity_feed_content').each(function() {
       var divHeightFeedPhoto=$(this).find('.activity_feed_content_link').outerHeight(true);
       divHeightFeedPhoto+=5;
       $('.activity_feed_content_info').css('top',divHeightFeedPhoto);
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I highly recommend using Zepto or jQuery instead of using pure javascript.  Secondly, there's probably a way to accomplish what you want with just HTML and CSS. If you share your code, what you've tried and what you're trying to do we may be able to help you better.  But since all we have is your question about javascript here is how you can accomplish what you're asking in jQuery:

```
$('.feed_css_class').each(function() {
    // get the height of the image in the feed
    var imageHeight = $(this).find('img').first().height()

    // set the bottom of the .menu_div
    $(this).find('.menu_div').css('bottom', imageHeight + 'px');
});
```